# Type string or object with appropriate key TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

My languageSchema can be a string or an object with the 'Etc' key. I have an interface:

```
let getLanguageSchema = (language: string): string => languagesSchemas[language];

interface IReduxProps {
    languageSchema:
        string
        | {
              Etc: {
                  listEmpty: string;
              };
          };
}
```

Component:

```
let EmptyList: React.FC<IReduxProps> = (props) => {
    let { languageSchema } = props;

    return (
        <div className="mt-5 text-center grey">
            <i className="now-ui-icons files_paper fs-4" />
            <h3 className="mb-0">{languageSchema.Etc.listEmpty}</h3>
        </div>
    );
};

let mapStateToProps = (state: IReduxState): IReduxProps => ({
    languageSchema: getLanguageSchema(state.common.language),
});
```

TypeScript compiler says: 'Property 'Etc' does not exist on type 'string | { Etc: { listEmpty: string; }; }'.   Property 'Etc' does not exist on type 'string'.'

What is the right way to set appropriate type for property that can be object or string?

Comment: There is no error with this code. The error you are describing would be from something else which is trying to access this object incorrectly. Please post the code that is actually producing the error. My guess is that you need a type guard.

Comment: The typescript playground might help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Ok, this code assumes that the value is always going to be an object with `Etc` property even though the type says it could also just be a string. Why are you confident that the value isn't just a string as the type says it might be?

Comment: As you can see the value can be an object with a property ‘Etc’. Sorry, I don’t quite understand your question.

Comment: Yes, but the value can also just be a string. What is supposed to happen in your JSX if the value is a string and not and object with property `Etc`?

Comment: It will be okay for TypeScript compiler

Comment: No, it's not ok to try to access `Etc` on a string. How do you expect `languageSchema.Etc.listEmpty` to work (at runtime) if `languageSchema` is a string?

Comment: I meant just to set up languageSchema to string without union operator. I understand it won't work if I try to access 'Etc' property on a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220625/discussion-between-ccarton-and-s-kamianiok).

Comment: I had exactly the same problem.  It works fine for assigning values but complains when you try to evaluate (e.g. in an "if" statement).  Glad to see that I am not alone.

Answer (score 0):

one Solution that might solve this issue, is to

- let the `IReduxProps` property accept only string
- and then convert the variable to string and then parse it as an object `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(languageSchema))`.

Interface :

```
 let getLanguageSchema = (language: string): string => languagesSchemas[language];

 interface IReduxProps {
    languageSchema: string 
 }
```

Component

```
const EmptyList: React.FC<IReduxProps> = (props) => {
  const { languageSchema } = props;

  const laanguageSchemaObjectType: { Etc: { listEmpty: string } } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(languageSchema));

  return (
    <div className="mt-5 text-center grey">
      <i className="now-ui-icons files_paper fs-4" />
      <h3 className="mb-0">{laanguageSchemaObjectType.Etc.listEmpty}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IReduxState): IReduxProps => ({
  languageSchema: getLanguageSchema(state.common.language),
});
```